# auto upgrading iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, app-store, upgrade

Is there some way to implement an auto-upgrade for an iPad app.
I would like to be able to have my app check for updates, and then upgrade itself.
As far as I am concerned the app can retrieve the update from the app-store, but:

I would like the interface to be app internal: User should just have to press an OK button for the upgrade to start (all this time staying within the app)

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have display a notification to inform an update is available on you app and you can redirect the user to the AppStore, but an update can only be download from the AppStore.

This will reinstall the new version of your app. So **you can't** stay in the app to update (You need to go to the appStore and qui the app during the update).

Internally, you can only update some content for you app (not add new native code) but not with a real AppStore update.

Comment: can you please provide some information or link which explains how the app can find if an update is available?

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not allow apps to download, install, or execute code that is not included in the original app submitted to Apple.  The App store upgrade cannot be automatically started.

the best you can do is determine if the app store has a newer update, then prompt the user to install it by linking directly to the app page in the app store.  They will still have to click the correct buttons to start the process.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible, it's not allowed by Apple. Your app will be rejected.

Unless you only update contents of your app, e.g. cooking receipts.